# How to get domain name in Windows using command?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I need a similar command to Linux' [domainname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/domainname) on Windows without using any third-party application.

Is there such a command?

Comment: For information - domain name of computer and domain name of the logged-in user might _not_ be same.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try:

```
echo %USERDOMAIN%
```

or

```
echo %USERDNSDOMAIN%
```

If that still doesn't work, you can try using `systeminfo`:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain"
```

Comment: %Userdomain% would give the domain of the user, not necessarily same as the domain name of the computer. http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-domain-name-command-line/

Answer (score 9):

You can run below mentioned command on command prompt to get the desired information:

```
set user
```

It gives us lot more information in addition to domain name (Refer screenshot):

[image]

List of details returned by the command are as below:

1. User DNS Domain
2. User Domain
3. User Domain Roaming Profile
4. User Name
5. User Profile

**Important Note**: Domain in which your computer is registered *might not* be the same as the one in which the logged-in user is registered. Reader is encouraged to explore - [transitivity and direction in domain trust](https://medium.com/tech-jobs-academy/trust-relationships-within-active-directory-directory-services-9f18b3a9e7da). This will help you to know about how a user registered in one domain can login to a computer registered in a *different* domain.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add my own solution just in case someone needs a fast way to do it.

My approach is using registry to get domain info:

```
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" /v "Domain"
```

Answer (score 2):

The %USERDOMAIN% and the network computer domain can be different.  The systeminfo command will get the right answer but it is SLOW!  Here is a solution I've used:

```
@REM + find the computer domain name
 FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`ipconfig /all`) DO (
     @((ECHO %%a | findstr /i /c:"Primary Dns Suffix") && SET _str=%%a) > NUL 2>&1
 )
 FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a IN ("%_str%") do SET _computerDomain=%%a
 SET _computerDomain=%_computerDomain: =%

 SET _fqdn=%COMPUTERNAME%.%_computerDomain%
```

Answer (score 2):

@Mike: fine solution - but I had some problems with it in a multi-language enviroment.
I have German and English servers.

I changed your script to use ***wmic.exe***:

```
@REM + Find the computer domain name
@echo off
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`wmic.exe COMPUTERSYSTEM GET DOMAIN /Value`) DO (
      @((ECHO %%a | findstr /i /c:"Domain=") && SET _str=%%a) > NUL 2>&1
)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=^=" %%a IN ("%_str%") do SET _computerDomain=%%a
SET _computerDomain=%_computerDomain: =%
SET _fqdn=%COMPUTERNAME%.%_computerDomain%
echo %_fqdn%
```

Thx for your idea

Answer (score 1):

One line is enough to get the domain using a local user:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%a IN (`wmic.exe COMPUTERSYSTEM GET DOMAIN /Value ^|find /i "domain"`) DO set _computerDom=%%a
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here aren't quite right.   The settings mentioned are for the *configured* domain, however that may not be the domain the computer is actually on.   The domain changes depending on what the computer is connected to - one WiFi connection may go to one domain, and a different one to another.   Then connecting on VPN will put you in yet another domain.   In all the cases the registry setting shown, and the USERDOMAIN and USERDNSDOMAIN environment variable values will remain unchanged.

To get the actual domain on which the computer is connected - use the "ipconfig" command line command, and see the "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" value.   Note, for instance that if you disconnect or disable your connection, that will go away, indicating (correctly) that you are no longer in any domain.

A computer can, in fact, be connected on multiple domains, even, by connecting multiple ethernet ports, wifi ports, etc. to different places.

Answer (score 0):

To offer ***PowerShell* solutions**:

Using **CIM (WMI)**:

```sh
# DNS domain name only.
(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain

# FQDN (fully qualified domain name, including hostname)
$env:COMPUTERNAME + '.' + (Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain
```

Using **.NET**, which **also works on non-Windows platforms**:

```sh
# DNS domain name only.
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('').HostName -replace '^[^.]+\.?'

# FQDN (fully qualified domain name, including hostname)
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('').HostName
```